# Applying DDD principles in a RESTish web service

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, domain-driven-design

I am developing an RESTish web service. I think I got the idea of the difference between aggregation and composition. Aggregation does not enforce lifecycle/scope on the objects it *references*. Composition does enforce lifecycle/scope on the objects it *contain/own*.

If I delete a composite object then all the objects it contain/own are deleted as well, while the deleting an aggregate root does not delete referenced objects.

**1)**
If it is true that deleting aggregate roots does not necessary delete referenced objects, what sense does it make to not have a repository for the references objects? Or are aggregate roots as a term referring to what is known as composite object?

**2)**
When you create an web service you will have multiple endpoints, in my case I have one entity `Book` and another named `Comment`. It does not make sense to leave the comments in my application if the book is deleted. Therefore, book is a composite object. I guess I should **not** have a repository for comments since that would break the enforcement of lifecycle and rules that the book class may have. However I have URL such as (examples only):

```
GET /books/1/comments
POST /books/1/comments
```

Now, if I do not have a repository for comments, does that mean I have to load the book object and then return the referenced comments? Am I allowed to return a list of Comment entities from the BookRepository, does that make sense? The repository for Book may eventually become rather big with all sorts of methods. Am I allowed to write JPQL (JPA queries) that targets comments and not books inside the repository? What about pagination and filtering of comments. When adding a new comment triggered by the POST endpoint, do you need to load the book, add the comment to the book, and then update the whole book object?

What I am currently doing is having a own CommentRepository, even though the comments are deleted with the book. I could need some direction on how to do it correct. Since you are exposing not only root objects in RESTish services I wonder how to handle this at the backend.

I am using Hibernate and Spring.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on programmers.se.

Answer (score 0):

Your REST resources do not have to be an exact match with your JPA entities. Even if you are not going to expose comments as a root REST resource, sometimes it still makes sense to model it as a JPA entity and have a repository for it. A few points to support this:

- If you anticipate large amount of comments for a book, saving a
  comment by adding it to `Book.comments` collection may be very
  inefficient.
- Editing and deleting comments will be much easier when `Comment` is
  an entity and has its own ID.
- Pagination implementation may be very
  inefficient if `Comment` is a value object.

What I would do is:

- Two entities: `Book` and `Comment`
- A foreign key in DB that ensures that
  all comments are deleted when a book is.
- A repository for each entity. `CommentRepository` would have a method `findByBook()`
- /book/{id}/comments in REST interface